# User click saving with .netcore

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to .netcore. I have a working application, on which I am working on. I want to track the user click and save in the database. Forexample, If the user search for something and click on the search result lets say 2nd result, I want to save that result in the database and put the score of it as 1, for future suggestions. 
I have tried to search the internet for this, but no help till now.

Comment: responde to click events with an ajax post/call to a controller, in which you send what was when clicked.

Comment: @Isparia Thank you for your answer. Can you explain a little more? Do you have any tutorial or something for it as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example like this, i wrote this blank, but this should do what you want (from the logic), if you implement it like this. Database implementation ect, is on your side since i dont know your models.

Javascript:

```
$('li[data-result]').click(function(){
  var result = $(this).data('result');
  var keyword = $(this).data('keyword');
  console.log(`/click/searchrecording?result=${result}&keyword=${keyword}`);
  /*
  $.ajax({
    url: `/click/searchrecording?result=${result}&keyword=${keyword}`,
    method: 'GET',
    succsess: function(){
      console.log('recorded Click');
    }
  });
  */
})
```

Html / Razor

```
<ul>
@foreach(var result in @Model.Results)
{
  <li data-result="@result.Id" data-keyword="@Model.Keyword">@result.Text</li>
}
<ul>
```

To Record the clicks:

```
public class ClickController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> SearchRecording([FromQuery] string result [FromQuery] string keyword)
    {
       /* Record to Database Async */
       return Ok();
    }
}
```

To Perform your Search:

```
public class SearchController
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromQuery] string keyword)
    {
       var results = await SearchInDatabase(keyword);
       var model = new SearchResultViewModel();
       model.Keyword=keyword;
       model.Results = results.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rank)
       return View(model);
    }
}
```